# WordPress: Add action for each custom post type

Tags: wordpress, action

Im looking to add an action for each of the custom post types registered on my WordPress site (when a custom post type is  published).
Now I could just manually add one for each of the types I have like:

```
add_action( 'publish_book', 'function_title_to_call' );
add_action( 'publish_movie', 'function_title_to_call' );
...
```

But I wanted to ask if there is a way it could be done so its all automated?
I tried the following without luck:

```
$arguments = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false
);
$all_post_types = get_post_types( $arguments, 'names', 'and' );
foreach ( $all_post_types as $one_post_type ) {
    add_action( 'publish_' . $one_post_type, 'function_title_to_call' );
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you were doing is the right way to 'automate' it, assuming your post types come back in `$all_post_types`, assuming `public_book` and such are actual hooks, and assuming `function_title_to_call` is an actual function to call.

Comment: `$all_post_types` return all registered post types. `publish_book` is a actual hook that if used as in first example fires correctly and of course `"function_title_to_call"` refers to a existing function. Yet it does not work.

Comment: Then you're doing the right thing. Figure out where it stops working as you expect and why. See if the hooks get added. See if your function gets called. See if your function gets called if you manually register the hook in the smae place. Debugging is part of your job by necessity; we can't do it for you.